# How to neglect a backslash of the text while using regular expression re.search in python?

Tags: python, python-re, regex-negation, python-regex

```
import re
a = "apple\c"
b = "applec"

re.search(pattern, a)
re.search(pattern, b)
```

while searching the pattern. In example ".+" for Any char one or more reptitions. Here I want to neglect "\" when ".+" identify "\" character in search.

Comment: Please update your code and provide the pattern which are you comparing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "neglect" do you mean remove from the output or don't include in the pattern, i.e. find `"apple"`?

If former:

```
>>> a.replace('\\', '')
'applec'
```

if latter:

```
>>> re.search(r'[^\\]*', a)
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='apple'>
```